# Is it possible to run a VirtualBox virtual machine inside a terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, terminal

I've downloaded an application packaged as a Virtual Machine from [this website](https://bitnami.com/stacks); basically, these images are higly specialized contained systems that acts as a server for a specific application, in example Wordpress, without having to install it on the main system. This is useful for trying them or for compatibility issues, these images are fully working out of the box.

Once started, the application can be accessed from a web browser in the host system.

Since these VM's are essentially text based servers only, I was wondering if it is possible to run them entirely from a terminal or a virtual TTY. I know that there is a CLI interface (`VBoxManage`) to control them, but as far as I know, the VM's always start in their own separate GUI window.

Is it possible to do that?

*My host machine runs Linux, specifically openSUSE*

Comment: They just start as individual containers. There is no need for the window. See also [Chapter 7. Remote virtual machines, 7.1.2. VBoxHeadless, the remote desktop server](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless)

Comment: You should investigate using [Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/explore/). Same idea, but much lighter on your system (and a lot faster to start/stop).

Comment: @thank you, I'll have a look, VirtualBox manual is pretty big and sometimes it is easy to miss something

Comment: @xenoid I've tried using Docker, but the apps I'm trying to use [seem too complex to be easily managed](https://hub.docker.com/r/tuxgasy/dolibarr/), or maybe I am just not that expert about it; but the result is the same, I've lost a lot of time trying to make it work without success, and with these VB image I have a solution that works out of the box and get the job done; when I have more spare time I could try to put more effort into it but for now I'd like to spare me some headaches

Answer (score 0):

From `man vboxmanage`:

> ```
>    startvm
>           <uuid|vmname>...  [--type gui|sdl|headless|separate]
> ```

I believe the `headless` type is what you are looking for.